# Unable to focus on text input after using angular-ui-bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a button which is using angular-ui-bootstrap dropdown and a vanilla text input.  Once the page loads, I can freely enter text into the input box.  However, after clicking the button, I can no longer focus on the input box: focus continually jumps back to the dropdown button.

How do I fix this problem, or have I hit a bug (and I should raise an issue)?

Here is a simple example using code directly from angular-ui-bootstrap:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JbXo3WfLgrHoXcyC2If4?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

FWIW, this seems to be the offending function call: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/7a1d54c8c34265e0e1b7ac1b38f58b5867a2af49/src/dropdown/dropdown.js#L108

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you found an already found bug. Someone raised an issue for the ui-dropdown focus already...please check this link: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6372  and also this one which describes your issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6364

Comment: I just figured I was missing some small detail, didn't think it would be an *actual* bug. Thanks for the pointers